# Как зайти в ос ред ос если ни какие пароли не устанавливал при установке

Tags: linux, ос

Всем привет. Установил я ос ред ос 7.3.2 и убрал все галочки и только пароль Рут, который обязательный поставил user, но при включении требует вести пользователя и пароль, но user не походит и не удаётся войти в операционную систему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]